# PHP Replacing \" and \' with " and '

Tags: php, str-replace

I am trying to go through the array string I called out from database and filtered to a readable state. The string could have a lot of \' and \", below is just an example.

```
$content = 'It\'s go to somewhere \"GREAT\"!';
```

I am trying to use str_replace but it is not working...

```
$content1= str_replace('\\\'', "'", $content );
$newcontent= str_replace('\\\"', '"', $content1 );
```

Output should be 
It's go to somewhere "GREAT"!
instead.. I get 
It\'s go to somewhere \"GREAT\"!

I looked at preg_replace, but I don't quite get all the /.. or where to start on it.

Please help.

Comment: btw: do you know you can pass arrays to `str_replace()`?

Comment: Are you trying to remove "smart" quotes or slashes from quotes? Your title looks like smart quotes..

Comment: Answer suggested to use Stripslashes(). I totally didn't find that when I did my searching. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: The answer also might be to turn off magic quotes if your PHP configuration is doing that; or additionally if this data is already written..

Comment: Wish I didn't even ask this question. Stripslashes was very straight forward... getting pinged for it ;\. Yeah, the DB pull data was with the backslash already, so Stripslashes works great

Comment: But the question should be how did the data get into the DB with the `\`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how

```
            $content = 'It\'s go to somewhere \"GREAT\"!';
            $content = stripslashes($content);
            echo $content;
```

Comment: Thank you. stripslashes worked great... didn't even.. occur in my mind to look for that

Comment: Selected as answer because Lucky answered quicker!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is [`stripslashes($str)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

> Returns a string with backslashes stripped off. (\' becomes ' and so on.) Double backslashes (\) are made into a single backslash ().

```
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
echo stripslashes($str);
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm getting pinged for this.